# jquery .show() by php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger jquery .show() events triggered by php variables.

Here's my .php (which draws from a form submission on a separate page):

```
    $last_pic_displayed = trim($_POST["last_pic_displayed"]);
    if ( strlen($last_pic_displayed) <= 0 )
        {  $last_pic_displayed = trim($_GET["last_pic_displayed"]);  }
```

and here's my .show() code:

```
    <script>
    var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";
    lpic = parseInt(lpic);
    if (lpic == 0) {
        $("#1").show();
    }
    </script>
```

I use variations on this script for multiple divs with the intention that the correct $last_pic_displayed; value will trigger the correct div to show, but so far none have.

Here's an example of the form that's posting data to my php:

```
    <form id="buttons" action="process_form.php" method="post">

        <label for="child_name"><img src="images/enter_name_text.png" alt="Enter Your Name" id="name_text"></label>
        <input type="text" id="child_name" name="child_name" />



            <section>
                <input checked="checked" id="radio1" name="last_pic_displayed" type="radio" value="0" />
                <label for="radio1"><img src="images/3_letter_text.png" alt="3 Letter Words" class="level_text">
                </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <input checked="checked" id="radio2" name="last_pic_displayed" type="radio" value="6" />
                <label for="radio1"><img src="images/4_letter_text.png" alt="4 Letter Words" class="level_text">
                </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <input checked="checked" id="radio3" name="last_pic_displayed" type="radio" value="13" />
                <label for="radio1"><img src="images/5_letter_text.png" alt="5 Letter Words" class="level_text">
                </label>
            </section>

            <section id="submit_button">
                <input type="image" name="submit" src="images/submit.png" />
            </section>



    </form>
```

Here is an example of the section of code that I'm trying to get to show when the submitted form data matches a certain value along with my script in relation:

```
    <div class="word" id="1" data-value="1">

<img src="images/Bat.png" class="letter_text">

<form id="f1" action="results.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="child_name" value="<?php $child_name; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="running_score" value="<?php $running_score; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_pic_displayed" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="correct_spelling" value="BAT" />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_pic_flag" value="NO" />
    <input type="hidden" name="level" value="3_letter" />
    <input type="text" name="submitted_spelling" />
    <input type="image" class="submit" src="images/submit.png" />
</form>

</div>

<script>
    var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";
    lpic = parseInt(lpic);
    if (lpic == 0) {
        $("#1").show();
    }
    alert(lpic);
</script>
```

I'm pretty new at all this, so I definitely appreciate your help.

**EDIT:** Updated with syntax corrections; problem currently persists.

**EDIT2:** Updated with form example.

**EDIT3:** Updated with parseInt() and example of the div I'm trying to show.

Comment: lpic = 0 should be == ?, you are now assigning 0 to lpic, which is always false and will never enter your if..

Comment: What do you expect last_pic_displayed to be? Did you check what you actually get? also, you have $_GET and you are checking for $_POST, that's probably wrong also?

Comment: Change if (lpic = 0) { this to if (lpic == 0) {

Comment: I expect last_pic_displayed to be a value from an HTML5 form, and it should be a number.

I didn't write any of the .php code, but other php variables drawn from the same syntax have worked when I've made echo calls to them.

Comment: I changed lpic = 0 to the appropriate lpic == 0 to no avail.

Comment: Can u also show the html that will or will not be shown when a user clicks the button? + does firebug throw any errors? And what's in alert(lpic) ?

Comment: Firebug hasn't thrown any errors.

Alert(lpic) displays the expected integer value of last_pic_displayed. Interestingly, when alert(lpic) is placed at the end of the script the appropriate div is shown as long as the alert() is active. Once the alert is dismissed, the div hides again.

Comment: Made [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mragm6L/2/) to reproduce but can not find any error. Whats your Browser? Are there any events or style things with the class `.word`? Is there another `div` with the id `#1`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parseInt() the "lpic" variable Like that way :

> ```
> var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";
> lpic = parseInt(lpic);
> if (lpic == 0) {
>     $("#1").show();
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I've added lpic = parseInt(lpic); to my script, but the problem persists.

Comment: Actually you need to check first what really this variable get. 
var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";
alert it like : alert(lpic); then proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

```
use it:-

    var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";
lpic = parseInt(lpic);
if (lpic == 0) {
    $("#1").show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! I've added lpic = parseInt(lpic); to my script, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script>
    var lpic = "<?php echo $last_pic_displayed; ?>";  // this must in ""   
    if (lpic == '0') {                // must be == instead =
        $("#1").show();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. I have implemented them, but the function still isn't working.

Comment: actually, if `var lpic="3"`, then the if condition needs modification `if (lpic=="3")` OR `if (parseInt(lpic)==3)`